# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING ""

Tags: php

Sorry,

i feel so stupid right now but how can i do this on the right way:

```
'.str_replace(' ', '+','$fetch['title']).'
```

without the `'` it's easy but i don't know how to put a str_replace on this code line

```
'.$fetch['title'].'
```

i tried:

```
 '.str_replace(' ', '+','$fetch['title']).'
```

//

```
str_replace(' ', '+',''.$fetch['title']).'
```

Comment: Even stackoverflow hightlights your mistake. If you want real help - show the real and complete code that could demonstrate the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'.str_replace(' ', '+',$fetch['title']).'
```

Comment: Thank you sorry for this question feel so dumb

Comment: Don't worry, it's a matter of fresh eyes ;)